# Two way associative array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function `compare()` which when given an even letter of the alphabet returns the letter of index one below it and when given an odd letter of the alphabet returns the letter of index one above it (up to the letter 'e'). As such:

```
function compare(letter) {
    var arr = {'a':'b', 'b':'a', 'c':'d', 'd':'c', 'e':'f', 'f':'e'}
    return arr[letter]
}
```

The problem is that this array is going to be very long, and I feel like repeating each element in reverse is a bit of a waste. Is there a way of modifying the function so that I can store something like

```
arr={'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'e':'f'}
```

Instead of

```
arr={'a':'b', 'b':'a', 'c':'d', 'd':'c', 'e':'f', 'f':'e'}+
```

Comment: This seems like a homework question?  If so, please read [*How do I ask and answer homework questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/634824)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an object or array for this, you can use the char code to determine what the new code should be.  Something like so

```js
function getLetter(letter) {
  var code = letter.charCodeAt(0);
  var newCode = code % 2 == 0 ? code - 1 : code + 1;
  return String.fromCharCode(newCode);
}

console.log(getLetter('a'));
console.log(getLetter('b'));
console.log(getLetter('c'));
console.log(getLetter('d'));
console.log(getLetter('e'));
console.log(getLetter('f'));
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `newCode = code + (code%2)*2-1;` at the cost of some readability

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the array concept.
`arr = {'a':'b', 'b':'a', 'c':'d', 'd':'c', 'e':'f', 'f':'e'}` is not an array, but a Hash.

The correct way should be:

```
function compare(letter){
    var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
    var index = arr.indexOf(letter)
    return index % 2 == 0 ? arr[index + 1] : arr[index - 1]
}
```

`indexOf` returns the position of the item you are checking. Then we check if it's odd or even and return the below/above corresponding letter.

Comment: Would many people consider the letter 'a' to be the 0 letter of the alphabet?

Comment: OP said [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), not array. A JavaScript object is indeed an implementation of an associative array, so the terminology is technically correct—at least as correct as "hash." JavaScript programers usually just call it an "object."

Comment: @Bert if you want to letter 'a' be 1, just add 1 to the index value.

Comment: @Jordan my bad, I missed the title telling it's an associative array. I only read the description. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it's even or odd, and return the letter above/below.

```
function compare(letter) {
  var code = letter.charCodeAt(0);
  if (code % 2) {
    return String.fromCharCode(code + 1);
  } else {
    return String.fromCharCode(code - 1);
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
compare('a')
"b"
compare('c')
"d"
compare('b')
"a"
compare('d')
"c"
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

const pairs = alphabet.reduce((acc, letter, index) => {
  acc[letter] = alphabet[index+1] || alphabet[0];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(pairs)
```